# Functions in "switch" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, hash, switch-statement

I have the javascript stated bellow. I need to execute some functions instead of alert(), but it doesn't work... I need to include **document.getElementById("").innerHTML=""** function. I'm not very experienced in js and I will be very grateful if somebody will explain how to do that and where is a problem.

```
window.onload = function locationHashChanged() {
    var hashx = location.hash;
    switch (hashx) {
       case '#basketball':
           alert('1');
           break;
       case '#football':
           alert('2');
           break;
       default:
           alert('3');
    }
    window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
}
```

Comment: Do you see any of your alerts? if not , try to set alert before the switch to make sure the location and hashx are properly defined.

Comment: I see all of alerts, but only if function name is defined. I don't know why it goes such way =(

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a function name to the assignment of `window.onload`.

You need to assign an `anonymous function` instead, such as

```
window.onload = function(){
  // stuff
}
```

Comment: But when I use anonynous function hash detection doesn't work. I get default alert.

Comment: Naming a function defined by the [`function` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) is optional, but totally valid here.

Comment: ok. now it works with document.getElementById , but is it possible to include any "function ()" for "switch case"?

Comment: great, not quite sure what you mean though

Comment: )) I mean that when I replace alert() with myfunction () it doesn't work. (excuse my English =)

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, you'll have to update your example above

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem here is that you're defining `window.onload` *after* the load event has taken place, which means that your handler is not being called. Either that, or some other code is overwriting your handler.

You *don't* need to wait until the `window`'s load event for adding a `hashChange` event handler, so just use:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
    var hashx = location.hash;
    switch (hashx) {
       case '#basketball':
           alert('1');
           break;
       case '#football':
           alert('2');
           break;
       default:
           alert('3');
}
```